# Laravel Redirect Loop

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am trying to access the Admin Control Panel with the username and password saved in the .env file, confirming it by comparing what is in session. But I am getting a redirect loop when trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Routes

```
Route::middleware(['admin.login'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [AdminLogin::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/admin', [AdminLogin::class, 'loginSubmit'])->name('admin.login.submit');
});

Route::middleware(['admin.panel'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/news', [NewsController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.news.index');
    Route::get('/admin/news/create', [NewsController::class, 'create'])->name('admin.news.create');
    Route::post('/admin/news/', [NewsController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.news.store');
    Route::get('/admin/news/{news}/edit', [NewsController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.news.edit');
    Route::put('/admin/news/{news}/update', [NewsController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.news.update');
    Route::delete('/admin/news/{news}/delete', [NewsController::class, 'delete'])->name('admin.news.delete');
});
```

Middleware

OpenAdminLoginWhenPasswordIsNotCorrect

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userHasAccessToTheContent = Session::get('userHasAccessToTheContent', false);
        if ($userHasAccessToTheContent === false) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

OpenAdminPanelWhenPasswordIsCorrect

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userHasAccessToTheContent = Session::get('userHasAccessToTheContent', false);
        if ($userHasAccessToTheContent === true) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.news.index');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'admin.login' => \App\Http\Middleware\OpenAdminLoginWhenPasswordIsNotCorrect::class,
        'admin.panel' => \App\Http\Middleware\OpenAdminPanelWhenPasswordIsCorrect::class,
    ];
```

Controllers/AdminLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class AdminLogin extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function loginSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $expectedPass = config('content.password');
        if (! empty($expectedPass) and $password === $expectedPass) {
            Session::put('userHasAccessToTheContent', true);

            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin.news.index');
        }
    }
}
```

NewsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\News;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $news = News::all();

        return view('admin.index', ['news' => $news]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate(
            [
                'title' => 'required|string',
                'category' => 'required|string',
                'content' => 'required|string',
            ]
        );

        $newArticle = News::create($data);

        return redirect(route('admin.news.index'));
    }

    public function edit(News $news)
    {
        return view('admin.edit', ['news' => $news]);
    }

    public function update(News $news, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate(
            [
                'title' => 'required|string',
                'category' => 'required|string',
                'content' => 'required|string',
            ]
        );

        $news->update($data);

        return redirect(route('admin.news.index'))->with('success', 'News Updated Successfully');
    }

    public function delete(News $news)
    {
        $news->delete();

        return redirect(route('admin.news.index'))->with('success', 'News Deleted Successfully');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect is a normal result of your middleware `OpenAdminLoginWhenPasswordIsNotCorrect`, this middleware is applied to `/admin` route , so each time you visit this route and you are not logged in ,it will check `userHasAccessToTheContent` and it is false, so it will redirect back to `/admin` again and check and redirect , it is inside a loop. you have to modify your middleware.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userHasAccessToTheContent = Session::get('userHasAccessToTheContent', false);
        if ($userHasAccessToTheContent === true) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.news.index');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```